# Dynamically Create Always Encrypted Table in SQL Server using c#

Tags: sql-server-2016

Is there any way to dynamically create an always encrypted table in C# code, just like we how we create a table dynamically in c# code?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean to create a Always Encrypted SQL server table in c#?

Comment: @Nick Sql Table where columns values are encrypted and stored. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)